# Wowza HTTP Provider own class

Tags: module, wowza

I created a new http provider class to serverinfo information using this article:

https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?182-How-to-get-detailed-server-info-with-an-HTTP-Provider

I change the name from HTTPServerInfoXML to HTTPServerStatsXML and compiled on Eclipse.

I added the configuration to VHost.xml and restarted the Wowza but the access to /stats not work. It still loading and never complete.

PlugiN:

lib/wms-plugin-httpserverstatsxml.jar

VHost.xml

```
<HTTPProvider>
<BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.http.HTTPServerStatsXML</BaseClass>
<RequestFilters>stats*</RequestFilters>
<AuthenticationMethod></AuthenticationMethod>
</HTTPProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

While we don't have the entire context here (cannot see your VHost.xml configuration), I'd suggest you review the following:

- Be sure that you add the http provider under the appropriate port?  i.e. if you add it to 8086 it should show under the following address:

> http://[wowza-ip]:8086/stats

If you add it under hostport 1935 then:

> http://[wowza-ip]:1935/stats

- Ensure that you don't add it below the wildcard entry for com.wowza.wms.http.HTTPServerVersion as it will never get picked up.
- You should specify a AuthenticationMethod to be one of the following: none, admin-basic, or admin-digest.
- Ensure the access logs do not show any entries that indicate the provider does not exist.
- Review configuration guidelines for [http providers](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?733-How-to-create-an-HTTP-Provider).